# Jenkins execute shell

Tags: shell, jenkins, execute

I have a jenkins job which is having 5 build scripts configured in job execute shell. Now I have a flag in  script#1 if it's false then I don't want to run remaining 4 build scripts and directly exit then build results should be pass.

But now even after checking script#1 flag is false it's exiting from script#1 and executing remaining 4 build scripts then all the 4 scripts are  failing due to dependency with script#1 finally my jenkins build status is failed.

I want after checking script#1 job could exit and directly jenkins job status should be "pass"

Is there anyway in jenkins itself to control this flow? without writing any code in scripts?

Jenkins error :

```
------------
23:37:16 Nothing to build
23:37:16 SRV_SKIP_UNNECESSARY_BUILDS is set to 1
23:37:16 Exiting now...
23:37:16 +++/usr/atria/bin/cleartool rmview -f -tag swrel_sre_icx_test_ashok_diffreportvu_20180118_233612
23:37:30 SRE_FYI: No rebuild necessary for sre_icx_test_ashok since previous full build[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
23:37:30 [EnvInject] - [ERROR] - The given properties file path '/var/tmp/jenkins/workspace/Test/sre_icx_test_ashok/srv_env_strip' doesn't exist.
23:37:30 [EnvInject] - [ERROR] - Missing file path was resolved from pattern '${WORKSPACE}/srv_env_strip' .
23:37:30 [EnvInject] - [ERROR] - Problems occurs on injecting env vars as a build step: java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: /var/tmp/jenkins/workspace/Test/sre_icx_test_ashok at hudson.remoting.Channel@1c0be696:l42-up-ecbld-01: java.io.IOException: The given properties file path '/var/tmp/jenkins/workspace/Test/sre_icx_test_ashok/srv_env_strip' doesn't exist.
23:37:30 Build step 'Inject environment variables' changed build result to FAILURE
23:37:30 Build step 'Inject environment variables' marked build as failure
23:37:30 Set build name.
23:37:30 Unrecognized macro 'SRV_BUILD_LABEL' in '#22 - ${SRV_BUILD_LABEL}'
23:37:30 Archiving artifacts
23:37:30 SSH: Current build result is [FAILURE], not going to run.
23:37:30 [description-setter] Description set: ${SRV_BUILD_DIR}
23:37:30 Notifying upstream projects of job completion
23:37:30 Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could do so by acquiring a Jenkins plugin called "Fail The Build" and change your job so that:

- The first build step writes a flagvar=value to a file which can later be sourced by another script, and then exits with a failure. The failure will skip out of running subsequent build steps and go straight to the post-build actions.
- Then you can set in the post-build "Execute a set of scripts->Build steps->Execute shell". Set it to execute steps only if build fails, and then in the first step have it source the first build step's file written to see if it was an abort or an actual failed build. If a failed build, exit again with an error - otherwise let it go to the next post-build build step which calls Fail The Build to change the job status back to Success.

I have not tried this to see if it actually works.